# gun.user.recall() stores password as plain text in sessionStorage without encryption

Tags: passwords, session-storage, gun

I want to apply `gun.user` in my project.

When I store the user in sessionStorage using `user.recall(opt)`,

[This code in sea.js](https://github.com/amark/gun/blob/9f7c530922020c77680a37fd5ce68e13d9962317/sea.js#L876) stores password in `tmp` without encryption.

Is it okay? or..

Should I encrypt password before calling `.auth`?

Here is my code.

```
jq('#up').on('click', (e) => {
    let form = check();
    if(!form){ return }
    S.user.create(form.alias, form.pass, (ack) => {
        if(ack.err){ return S.tell(ack.err) }
        check.up = true;
        S.user.auth(form.alias, form.pass, logined);
    });
});

jq('#in').on('click', (e) => {
    let form = check();
    if(!form){ return }
    S.user.auth(form.alias, form.pass, logined);
});

let logined = (ack) =>{
    if(ack.err){ return S.tell(ack.err) }
    S.user.recall({sessionStorage: true});
}
```

---

+

I found the [document](https://gun.eco/docs/User#user-create) about `user.create()`.

> Passphrase that will be extended with PBKDF2 to make it a secure way
>   to login.

However, there is plane text in my session storage.

[image]

gun version is 0.2019.515.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@huhsame , great concern! (And btw, incredible GUN AR/VR demos on your twitter!)

> Browsers require domain-based security which sadly limits P2P security.

Unfortunately, `sessionStorage` is the safest best *browser* option:

- Credentials are not shared with servers (like cookies do).
- It keeps a user logged in on refresh.
- It **deletes the credentials** if you close the tabs.

Between page loads, encrypting the password **is a good idea but the problem is**, to keep the user logged in, the decryption key also has to be stored. :(

Storing credentials in `localStorage` is **unsafe**, which is why `sessionStorage` is better.

> Warning! Unless you use a Browser Extension (below) or Browsers adopt better solutions, an XSS leak can compromise credentials from `sessionStorage` - but even if you disable it, credentials can be pulled from in-memory without an Extension to protect accounts.

**PBKDF2** is used during the login process, not session management - again, it could be used there as well, but has the same limitations as above.

> Even `sessionStorage` does not work well for keeping users logged in.

As a result, you should consider other solutions. I've written more about other options here:

[Keeping a Gun DB user authenticated during a session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53578591/keeping-a-gun-db-user-authenticated-during-a-session/53741832#53741832)

## Better Security

For the **best security**, users would sadly need to install a browser extension, like our http://party.lol tool, until Browsers adopt this type of security natively, or offer better user-centric session management.